# Android Shared Preference Declaring Default Value

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

So I'm having a small issue with declaring the default value "ipAddress" in my onCreate function. ipAddress is declared in the bottom void but not for checking whether the ip exists. This is the code that I'm working with:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
    if (sharedPreferences.contains("ip")) {
        performLogin(etUsername, etPassword, sharedPreferences.getString("ip", ipAddress));
    }

    // declaring variebles
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    etIpAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIpAddress);

    // setting up things for login button
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ipAddress = etIpAddress.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);

            sharedPreferences.edit()
                    .putString("ip", ipAddress)
                    .apply();

            String username = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            performLogin(username, password, ipAddress);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this change in your code

```
..
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);

String ip=sharedPreferences.getString("ip",null);
if(ip!=null){
  performLogin(etUsername, etPassword, ip);
}
```

Comment: There's an issue with the variables within the performLogin. My etUsername, etPassword, and etIpAddress are declared at the top outside of the oncreate function.

Comment: And this is how my perform login goes    
        private void performLogin(String username, String password, String ipAddress) {
        try {
            Device.login(username, password, ipAddress, this);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            onLoginFailure(e);
        }
    }

Comment: @Lotse please be clear what your issue is. If the solution solved the problem mark it as accepted. If you have another problem, please write a new question with details.

Comment: Ye sorry about that, I will get around tomorrow (extremely busy).